# Devise JSON API returning 406 instead of 401 because of redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, authentication, devise, warden

I'm trying to get devise to return a 401 and error message when trying to request an endpoint without proper authentication.

Currently this is what is happening:

Started GET "/api/v1/home/index.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-27 02:40:22 +0000
Processing by HomeController#index as JSON
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms

Started GET "/api/v1/sign_in.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-27 02:40:22 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#new as JSON
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

How can I stop devise from bouncing me to sign_in and instead get it to just return a 401/json response.

I'm thinking this may have to do with a CustomFailureApp, which I have tried, but I'm not sure the CustomFailureApp is being called in this particular scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a custom failure app.

```
class JsonFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def respond
    self.status = 401
    self.content_type = 'json'
    self.response_body = '{"error" : "Authentication error"}'
  end
end
```

Add this to your devise initializer

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = JsonFailureApp
end
```